# Find domain of function $f(x)=(-\cos 3x)^{x^2+1}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find domain of function
>   $f(x)=(-\cos 3x)^{x^2+1}$

I have absolutely no idea how to go about it or is it something when the expression will be $ \frac{1}{f(x)} $ and in this moment $f(x)\not=0$?

Comment: if you are in real numbers, there is not a problem, any real number is convenient

Comment: This is not a division, it's an exponentiation. Exponentiation is not defined when the base is negative. When is $-\cos 3x$ negative? If the exponent could be zero or negative, then you would have that problem as well, but $x^2+1$ never is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make $f(x)$ a well defined real number you need $\cos (3x ) \leq 0$. Hence the domain of $f$  is $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} [\frac {2n\pi} 3 +\frac {\pi} 6,\frac {2n\pi} 3 +\frac {\pi} 2]$.